# angular different button view with translude

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create angular button directive with 2 views with translude or replace.
I have one button as icon and another as text but common logic

```
<md-button ng-click="startStaffingCtrl.startStaffing(startStaffingCtrl.group)"
       class="md-raised">Stuff group</md-button>

<md-button aria-label="Staff this group" ng-click="startStaffingCtrl.startStaffing(startStaffingCtrl.group)>
<md-icon md-svg-icon="core:people"></md-icon></md-button>
```

Now I using to set additional parameter to choose template

```
    function buttonStuffingDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            group: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: function () {
            let res;
            if (tAttrs.icon) {
             res = 'components/groups/staffing/staffingButton/buttonStaffingIconTemplate.html';
             } else {
             res = 'components/groups/staffing/staffingButton/buttonStaffingTemplate.html';
             }
            return res;
        },
        controller: 'StartStaffingController',
        controllerAs: 'startStaffingCtrl',
        bindToController: true
    };
}
```

Can you help me to solve this problem with translude or replace, without additional template?

Comment: Why can't the icon element just use ng-show or ng-if?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer.

```
    function buttonStuffingDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            group: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'components/groups/staffing/staffingButton/buttonStaffingTemplate.html',
        controller: 'StartStaffingController',
        controllerAs: 'startStaffingCtrl',
        bindToController: true,
        compile() {
            return function post(scope, $el, $attr) {
                $el.children('md-button').addClass($attr.class);
            };
        }
    };
}
```

// components/groups/staffing/staffingButton/buttonStaffingTemplate.html

```
   <md-button aria-label="Staff this group" 
       ng-click="startStaffingCtrl.startStaffing(startStaffingCtrl.group)">
       <span ng-transclude>Staffing button</span>
  </md-button>
```

Different views for button

```
     <button-stuffing group={{group._id}}>
          <md-icon md-svg-icon="core:people"></md-icon>
     </button-stuffing>


  <button-stuffing class="md-raised md-primary" group={{group._id}}>
       Start Staffing
  </button-stuffing>
```